# gmaps4rails working on DEV, but not on live (heroku site)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, gmaps4rails

On my website http://tehcoffee.com/ the gmaps4rails gem is not working. (except for the individual shop page http://tehcoffee.com/shops/1 where I'm calling it the simple way)

The bizarre thing is that it works on DEV. (I can paste source code if it's needed)

the gmaps4rails gem is up to date 10.2

It's being hosted on heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you didn't update something on your prod server (the gem itself or some cache).

Actually, here is an abstract of your html:

> Gmaps4Rails.markers = [{"description": "", "title": "My Location:
>   Seattle", "sidebar": "", "longitude": "-122.3308333", "latitude":
>   "47.6063889", "picture": "images/google-map-blue.png", "width": "32",
>   "height": "32"}];

Two things here tell me the gmaps4rails (or html cache) isn't updated:

- all empty fields are now removed to make js code lighter
- `longitude` and `latitude` have been replace with `lng` and `lat`

Comment: lng and lat was the key. Thank you sir! Thanks to google for making this backwards compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to plot too many shops. Try plotting 10, and then increment.

[image]

Comment: hopefully, google maps is able to handle much more markers :)